# Validação de campos no cshtml

Tags: html5, mvc

Tenho visto alguns exemplos para validar campos, mas todos eles eu que tenho que informar qual o campo ou controle a ser validado, ou seja, tenho que passar Nome dos controles. Caso eu tenho um formulário com 20 campos, fica aquele "linguição". Como eu faço para de uma única vez, validar os vários tipos de controles que eu tenho em meu formulário, como Inputs, Options e etc? Pode ser via javascript, jquery e etc....

Uso MVC 5 e essa validação é no meu CSHTML.

Comment: Quais são as validações? Como está sendo feito hoje? Edite sua pergunta e insira estas informações.

Answer (score 1):

Esses campos podem ser validados por meio de `data annotations` como neste exemplo que fiz no meu [blog](http://devrodrigosantos.wordpress.com/2014/03/17/data-annotations/), ou utilizando o jQuery validation como [neste exemplo](http://runnable.com/UZJ24Io3XEw2AABU/how-to-validate-forms-in-jquery-for-validation) (no jQuery validation os atributos que serão passados ao método devem ter o mesmo `name` do elemento HTML).